# pass parameters to control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASP .net project. I am trying to load a user control in a Control object with the following code and i am trying to pass a parameter to that control. On the debugging mode I get an error on that line saying that `The file '/mainScreen.ascx?matchID=2' does not exist.`. If I remove the parameters then it works ok. Can anyone help me to pass those parameters? Any suggestions?

```
    Control CurrentControl = Page.LoadControl("mainScreen.ascx?matchID=2");
```

Comment: Is `matchID` a property of your control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass the parameter via query-string notation because user controls are simply "a building blocks" referenced by virtual path.

What you can do instead is to make a public property and assign the value to it once the control is loaded:

```
public class mainScreen: UserControl
{
    public int matchID { get; set; }
}

// ...

mainScreen CurrentControl = (mainScreen)Page.LoadControl("mainScreen.ascx");
CurrentControl.matchID = 2;
```

You can now use the `matchID` inside your user control like the following:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = this.matchID;

    // Load control data
}
```

Note that the the control is participating in the page life cycle only if it's added into the page tree:

```
Page.Controls.Add(CurrentControl); // Now the "Page_Load" method will be called
```

Hope this helps.